# Best way to automatate getting data from Csv files to Datalake

Tags: hadoop, hbase, hdfs, datamart, bigdata

I need to get data from csv files ( daily extraction from différent business Databasses ) to HDFS then move it to Hbase and finaly charging agregation of this data to a datamart (sqlServer ).

I would like to know the best way to automate this process ( using java or hadoops tools )

Answer (score 2):

I'd echo the comment above re. Kafka Connect, which is part of Apache Kafka. With this you just use configuration files to stream from your sources, you can use KSQL to create derived/enriched/aggregated streams, and then stream these to HDFS/Elastic/HBase/JDBC/etc etc etc

There's a list of Kafka Connect connectors [here](https://www.confluent.io/product/connectors/).

This blog series walks through the basics:

- https://www.confluent.io/blog/simplest-useful-kafka-connect-data-pipeline-world-thereabouts-part-1/
- https://www.confluent.io/blog/blogthe-simplest-useful-kafka-connect-data-pipeline-in-the-world-or-thereabouts-part-2/
- https://www.confluent.io/blog/simplest-useful-kafka-connect-data-pipeline-world-thereabouts-part-3/

Comment: Thx Robin , i started reading about kafka connctors and
it seems easier and less expensive . I'll poc this part and see what happen .  Thx again and nice blog btw ;)

Answer (score 1):

Little to no coding required? In no particular order

- Talend Open Studio
- Streamsets Data Collector
- Apache Nifi

Assuming you can setup a Kafka cluster, you can try Kafka Connect

If you want to program something, probably Spark. Otherwise, pick your favorite language. Schedule the job via Oozie

If you don't need the raw HDFS data, you can load directly into HBase

Comment: Thx @cricket_007 for the answer . could you tell me please what do you mean by " why you can't land directely into hbase " ?

Comment: Write some code to parse a CSV and write into Hbase table. Since hbase is already over hdfs data, I don't see the need to put it into hdfs, and then load it into Hbase

Comment: i understand , actually , the there will be other application that need the same data and they want to extract it directly from hdfs . Only mine need a hbase .